# how to set list of valid characters in postgresql strings

Tags: postgresql

I want to make a username field in postgresql database of course usernames has name patterns

like using 0-9 a-z A-Z _ characters only how do I do such thing ?

I tried making the server check the username before it insert it into the database it works but it's like meh

Answer (score 1):

You could create your table with a check constraint on the `username` field:

```sql
CREATE TABLE courses (
    ...,
    username VARCHAR(50) CHECK (username ~ '^[A-Z0-9_]+$'),
    ...
);
```

The above check constraint is using a case insensitive regex to assert that the username contains only letters, numbers, or underscore.